# Multithreading - Not working simultaneous

Tags: c#, multithreading

I want to implement a multithread system (two threads will do) and I followed a tutorial

```
    Thread t1 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(threadA));
    Thread t2 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(threadB));
    t1.Start();
    t2.Start();
```

The output is unexpected for me as it shows:
"threadA"
"threadA"
"threadA"
"threadB"
"threadB"
"threadB".
Is something wrong with my code? Many thanks.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with your code. This sort of behaviour is expected, especially if your threads consist of tight loops.

Comment: I assume thread A / thread B just loop 3 times? Try setting the loop to like 10,000 then see if you get the same results.

Comment: Great job not including the *other* relevent bits of code.

Comment: Please do not include languages in the title of your question.  That's what tags are for.

Comment: what other relevant bits of code are needed? they run 3 times and writeline the current thread... :x thanks for the answers

Comment: The question here is: what did you expect it to output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because in the time that it takes for you to go from `t1.Start()` to `t2.Start()`, your `t1` has already completed.

Try something like this if you want to see your code alternate a little

```
Thread t1 = new Thread(
    new ThreadStart(()=>
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine("ThreadA");    
            Thread.Sleep(3000)
        }
    }));
Thread t2 = new Thread(
    new ThreadStart(()=>
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine("ThreadB");    
            Thread.Sleep(1000)
        }
    }));
t1.Start();
t2.Start();
```

It should print something like this:

```
ThreadA
ThreadB
ThreadB
ThreadA
ThreadB
ThreadA
```

However, this just shows that you cannot guarantee any order when it comes to threading.

Comment: thanks, will try whis solution. Still don't understand why the terrible rating on my question. Is it something so obvious?

Comment: @DiogoMendonça I believe the rating is because you did not actually ask a question and/or say what you expected.

Answer (score 2):

The short of it is that threads execute when the CLR and OS schedule them to do so, based on a lot of implementation details that vary from OS to OS and CPU to CPU.

Use of the Thread class does avoid the ThreadPool, which is most of the CLR's level of control over thread scheduling, but the OS kernel still decides when threads run. In your case, where each Thread is simply outputting three lines to the console, it's totally expected that one thread would finish before the OS even kicks off the other one.

HOWEVER, you can never *guarantee* the order in which threads will run. So, if you were to loop this code (with Join() statements) and run it 100 times, you may see several different permutations of "threadA" and "threadB" displayed as the threads are scheduled at different times by the OS. If two EUs are available at EXACTLY the same time there will be significant overlap; if threadA is somehow considered less important than threadB, threadB may execute in its entirety before threadA even begins.